# Nestled query Log analytics

Tags: azure, query-string, azure-log-analytics

Hi i'm trying to get to a log event by nestling a query in the "where" of another query. is this possible?

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where resource_workflowName_s == "[Workflow Name]"
| where resource_runId_s == (AzureDiagnostics | where trackedProperties_PayloadID_g == "[GUID]" | distinct resource_runId_s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where resource_workflowName_s == "[Workflow Name]"
| where resource_runId_s in (
     toscalar(AzureDiagnostics 
              | where trackedProperties_PayloadID_g == "[GUID]" 
              | distinct resource_runId_s))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly Thank you! :)

Comment: @AzzefNeufeld Is is possible to write a ware condition that takes values from a previous join too?